# Called a function with "cout" statement inside a "cout" statement

Tags: c++, function, cout

I came across this rather vague behavior when messing around with code , here's the example :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int print(void);

int main(void)
{
    cout << "The Lucky " << print() << endl;     //This line
    return 0;
}

int print(void)
{
    cout << "No : ";
    return 3;
}
```

In my code, the statement with comment `//This line`is supposed to print out 
`The Lucky No : 3`, but instead it was printed `No : The Lucky 3`. What causes this behavior? Does this have to do with C++ standard or its behavior vary from one compiler to another?

Comment: Why do you believe that your expectation instead of the actual outcome is the more logical one? Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: Sidenote: Your `print` function is a nice example of a function with side-effects. Besides calculating a return value, it also changes global program state. Such functions are usually more difficult to reason about. Generally, strive towards functions that either compute a value *or* change state, but not both simultaneously.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The order of evaluation of arguments to a function is unspecified.  Your line looks like this to the compiler:

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, "The Lucky "), print()), endl);
```

The primary call in the statement is the one with endl as an argument.  It is unspecified whether the second argument, endl, is evaluated first or the larger sub-expression:

```
operator<<(operator<<(cout, "The Lucky "), print())
```

And breaking that one down, it is unspecified whether the function `print()` is called first, or the sub-expression:

```
operator<<(cout, "The Lucky ")
```

So, to answer your question:

> What causes this behavior? Does this has to do with C++ standard or its behavior vary from one compiler to another?

It could vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: That's totally possible, and I might begin to see it ;)

Comment: @atamanroman: In the following expression: `operator<<(operator<<(cout, "The Lucky "), print())` What do you think should happen first, **This:** `operator<<(cout, "The Lucky ")`, or **this:** `print()`?  Justify your answer.

Comment: I know, It's not defined and I get it know. So cout << "The lucky " + print() would be well defined? Deleted my answer (+1).

Comment: @atamanroman: Just for the sake of preciseness, you might want to be aware that there's a difference between "undefined" and "unspecified" behaviour. Roughly speaking, undefined behaviour means that anything can happen; unspecified behaviour means that what happens depends on the implementation (but implementations are not required to document what they do).

Comment: @atamanroman: the behavior isn't undefined, it's unspecified -- there's a difference.  The compiler is free to evaluate the parameters in whatever order (including a random order) that it finds best, it's not free to not evaluate a parameter at all or to blow up your toaster.

Comment: @atamanroman: `cout << "The lucky" + print()` would output `No :  lucky`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Can you please also explain how the statments translated to 'operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, "The Lucky "), print()), endl);
'

Answer (score 4):

Let's call the `operator <<` simply `operator` .

Now we can write

```
cout << "The Lucky"
```

as

```
operator(cout, "The Lucky")
```

The result of this operation is `cout`, and it is passed to next `<<`, so we can write

```
operator(operator(cout, "The Lucky"), print() )
```

It is a function invocation with two parameters, and the standard doesn't say anything about the order of their evaluation.

So with some compilers you really may get

```
The Lucky No : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In my compiler No: The Lucky 3 is the output.... it means that its behaviour varies from compiler to compiler.